# How can I add an imageview dynamically in the text view when click on button?

Tags: android, imageview

I want to add an image view dynamically in the text view when click on button.

I am using following code on button click

```
       ImageView imgv = new ImageView(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);
        imgv.setLayoutParams(params);
        imgv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imgv.setMaxHeight(50);
        imgv.setMaxWidth(50);
        imgv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        lineartext.addView(imgv,params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly want is the end result expected but if you want to set image in a textview use

```
public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)<br/>
```

For Example

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
```

Use 0 where you don't want images.

For more details refer following link:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: Thank you so much for your ans. but I want to add captured image in that image view not from drawable folder. actually when I click on button then I want to add an image view dynamically in text view and side by side capture image from camera and save it on that image view.

Comment: So it looks like when you click on button you want to open camera capture image and set it in the image view....if this is the requirement then create a LinearLayout with ImageView and TextView place them as needed, set visibility of the image view to gone. Then on click on button capture the image and set visibility of imageView as Visible and set the image...